# .NET RDP Codec?

Tags: .net, remote-desktop

Not sure if "codec" is the correct term, but I'm looking for an open source library so to speak to use in a small remote desktop application I am working on. Purely for me to learn and have fun with.

The basic functionality being very similar to the products out there, TeamViewer, LogMeIn, BeAnywhere etc...

1. Agent (Host Application)
2. Client (Sends TCP* connection request)
3. Agent receives connection and desktop is streamed
4. Ability to remotely control mouse, forward key combinations etc..

*?: Would TCP be the best thing to use?

**Key feature**: To work over LAN **and the Internet**. I've been looking over things like [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/), [ActiveX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380808%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I guess my key question here, let's say you were tasked with using some sort of RDP protocol within a .NET application *(as apposed to the much better C,C++ alternative)*, would you create something that perhaps automated the enabling of the built in Windows RDP or would you look at some other library, or create something bespoke yourself *(Like TeamViewer, although probably quite difficult in .NET)*.

**Some of my thoughts**:

1. Windows RDP probably is the worst option here, as you would no doubt run in to problems with port forwarding rules both locally and at a network firewall level.
2. For this reason, I presume it would make more sense to "stream" a direct connection from the viewing application an agent has to the client application? This is where my main question originates from, a search of pre-existing libraries for this type of connection.
3. Would a "middle man" server of some kind help resolve the problems of point 1 above? A proposed system like: **Client -> Server -> Agent** *(or is this an unnecessary complication?)*
4. I would prefer not to overlook data and traffic encryption, although I realize the complication level is reaching a fairly high point, I also imagine the use of .NET is making this quite a resource hungry project. However, I could feasibly incorporate RSA key sharing? I presume AES-256bit would be the thing to look at?

I apologize if I lack basic understanding here or if my terminology is not correct but I appreciate any suggestions and pointers from the seasoned members of SO.

Comment: Why would C/C++ be *"much better"*? ;-)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski erm, I presume it would be more light weight, probably faster as well as the possibility of being cross platform, that's if this was some sort of serious product not just me having some fun. Oh and because in my mind C++ is cooler than .NET (haha) In all honesty though I'm not sure :/ - Hope you have a few suggestions for me anyway, ;)

Comment: My suggestion would be to study the WinAPI (how to grab a screenshot, move the mouse, send keypresses to other applications etc) and how to P/Invoke the functions you need (that's the cumbersome part when you use .NET). Sending the info efficiently over the network will be complicated :) Good luck.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Thanks Lucas, what about connecting to .NET applications together, I guess I should be looking at sockets?

Comment: If you use TCP I'd rather use `NetworkStream`, it's much easier to use than raw sockets.